# Can a subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ be homotopy equivalent to $S^n$?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, homotopy-theory

Can a subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ be homotopy equivalent to $S^n$? I am pretty certain the answer is no and I suspect it might be provable using homology groups, but I do not see how. Note that, because $S^n$ is the one-point compactification of $\mathbb{R}^n$, this question is equivalent to asking whether $S^n$ is homotopy equivalent to one of its proper subsets.

Edit: By freakish's comment, the answer is no when the subset is a manifold. However, I am now less certain whether the answer is no for any subset by the example Tyrone showed.

Edit 2: As Maxime Ramzi pointed out, the answer is also no if $X$ is compact by Alexander duality.

Comment: You might want to look at the $n$th Homology groups.

Comment: @Brozovic Right. The nth homology group of $S^n$ is $\mathbb{Z}$. But I fail to see why a subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ cannot also have an nth homology group of $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: So do I. In fact, [here](http://www.logic.info.waseda.ac.jp/~eda/index.html) you will find a suggestion that things are not so clear cut...

Comment: By the topological Poincare conjecture, such subset would have to be homeomorphic to $S^n$. But that's impossible by the invariance of domain.

Comment: @freakish Wouldn't the subset need to be a manifold for that to hold?

Comment: @Anonymous ah, yes, you're right.

Comment: For $n=2$ the answer is no, since [planar sets are aspherical](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0166864101000050).

Comment: @Anonymous My approach works for every subset of $\Bbb R^n$ that are 'nice enough' so that they can be given a CW-complex structure. Isn't it?

Comment: @Brozovic it does, but embarrasingly few subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$ have CW homotopy type...

Comment: @Tyrone Yeah, that's true! Weird spaces like Hawaiian ear-ring are there in abundance! But nevertheless, while studying Mathematics, we are mostly looking at spaces with enough constraints put so that they are 'nice enough' to work with!

Comment: I think it's true when your subspace is compact and locally contractible, by Alexander duality (case $q=0$ here : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexander_duality , using stereographic projection to see your subspace as a  compact subspace of $S^n$)

Comment: @Brozovic Sorry if this is a dumb question, but why can't an n-dimensional CW complex embedded in $\mathbb{R}^n$ have $\mathbb{Z}$ as its nth homology group? I'm aware that n-dimensional CW complexes have trivial kth homology groups for k>n.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

By a corollary of the generalized Poincaré duality, referred as *Poincaré Alexander Lefschetz duality* in the book *Geometry and Topology* of Bredon, you can derive the following precious tool :

> **Corollary 8.5 (Bredon - G. & T.)** If $L$ is a proper compact subset of an orientable connected $n$-manifold $M$, then $\check H^n(L; G) = 0$ for any coefficient group $G$.

So, if $X$ is a compact subset of $\mathbb R^n$, $X$ can't have the (weak) homotopy type of an $n$-sphere. Now more generally, if $X\subset \mathbb R^n$ is any subset and if it is homotopy equivalent to the $n$-sphere, then you get maps $\mathbb S^n\to X$ and $X \to \mathbb S^n$ such that the compositions are homotopic to the identities. If $L$ is the image of $\mathbb S^n\to X$, then $\mathbb S^n\to L\to \mathbb S^n$ is homotopic to $1_{\mathbb S^n}$ so the maps induced in Cech cohomology verify that $$\check H^n(\mathbb S^n)\to \check H^n(L)\to \check H^n(\mathbb S^n)$$
is the identity, which is not possible because Corollary 8.5 of Bredon applies to $L$ which is compact and so, $\check H^n(L)=0$.